# Moment.js “Invalid date”

Tags: momentjs

I want to make the date format dd-mm-yyyy, but `var ilk`, son comes 'invalid date' ?

```js
$('#cmbAnketID').on('change', function (a) {

    var firstDate = a.added.element[0].attributes["data-bastar"].value;
    var secondDate = a.added.element[0].attributes["data-bittar"].value;

    var ilk = moment(firstDate.value, "DD/MM/YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var son = moment(secondDate.value, "DD/MM/YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    $("#ilkTarih").val(ilk);
    $("#ikinciTarih").val(son);

});
```

Comment: try removing `.value` in the moment(); You are getting the value and assigning it to a variable and then trying to get the value of this value.

Comment: i tried remove .value but not change, very interesting.

Comment: set a breakpoint in `DevTools` and check if the value is not undefined or null. If not copy the value here.

Comment: Thanx @Denisx , true format;
 var ilk = moment(firstDate, "DD/MM/YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD');